# Eclipse Java: "The import com.jidesoft cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, dependency-management

When trying to build/run my program i get an error with a dependency:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems: The import com.jidesoft cannot be resolved"

How do i properly include it in Eclipse?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajKns.png)

Comment: Formatted Error

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by download an external jar and adding it to the path via project properties. Another solution is to create a maven project and search through the available dependencies for maven.